# removing footer of the first page of preface in using gsm-l.cls

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I am using gsm-l.cls, which is downloadable from [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsbook?lang=en).
It defines a special style for chapters. In particular, the first page of each chapter has a footer consisting of short thick rule at the bottom right corner and the page numbering underneath.

How can I remove the rule and the page numbering for the first page of a preface, with changing the file gsm-l.cls allowed?

Here is my codes.

```
\documentclass{gsm-l}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Preface}
This book is ***.
\mainmatter
\include{chp1}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of my codes]

Comment: *"... first page of a preface, with changing the file gsm-l.cls allowed?"* - That part of the sentence after the comma is a bit confusing. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: Have you tried `\thispagestyle{empty}`?  (Always try the easiest thing first.  Trying to change this for one chapter via modifying `gsm-l.cls` would be beastly.)

Comment: @DuckDodgers after comma, I would like to say that I am allowed to change the cls file, or I can accept a solution of changing codes in the cls file. Sometimes people prefer achieving a goal without changing the cls file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes I've tried. It does not work.

Comment: Too bad that `\thispagestyle{empty}` doesn't work.  I suggest sending a request for help to tech-support@ams.org, and suggesting (in addition to asking for a solution) that the ability to use `\thispagestyle{empty}` be added to the class for just this purpose.  (I used to work on this class, and it really is beastly; the original implementor was tearing his hair out trying to get everything just right according to the spec he was given.)